# Help with Gronwall's Inequality

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

I'm trying to solve an extra credit hw problem that has to do with Gronwall's Inequality. I understand (or think I do) how to find an upper bound when $p=0$, but I'm unsure of how to handle the extra factors of $g(\tau)$. I know how to put the inequality into a differential form and use an integrating factor, but that's where I get stuck. Any pointers or tips on how to proceed would be great.

**Problem**

Let $g,f, \text{and } h$ be functions that are $\leq0$. Let $p$ be an integer constant $\leq0$. Then let the function $g(t)$ be bounded by:

$g(t)\leq f(t)+ \int_0^t{[g(\tau)]^{p+1}h(\tau)d\tau}$ and $f'(t)\leq0$.

Then $g(t)\leq$ ?

Comment: Are you supposed to prove Gronwall, or just apply it to this case?

Comment: I think apply it so I have some kind of upper bound for g(t). That's all the info my teacher gave us.

Comment: If $p+1$ is even, then $g(t) \le f(t)$.